# how to return an array of objects in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, arrays, object, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am doing a query in zf2 and i get back a `object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet)` that i have to a `foreach` on, in order to get to the properties.

I would like to get an array of objects by default.

here is some code i have:

factory

```
'address-mapper'  => function ($serviceManager) {
    $mapper = new Mapper\Address();
    $mapper->setDbAdapter($serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
    $mapper->setEntityPrototype(new Entity\Address);
    $mapper->setHydrator(new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods);

    return $mapper;
}
```

the query

```
public function fetchById()
{
    $select = $this->getSelect()->where(array('id' => $Id));
    return $this->select($select);
}
```

this gives me back:

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet)[459]
      protected 'hydrator' => 
        object(Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods)[415]
          protected 'underscoreSeparatedKeys' => boolean true
          private 'callableMethodFilter' => 
          ....
          ....
```

any ideas what i need to do?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590174/convert-zend-db-resultset-hydratingresultset-to-array-of-objects/16692849

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet` has a `toArray` method. So you can do this to get a  multi-dimension array of the results instead of a result set:

```
public function fetchById()
{
    $select = $this->getSelect()->where(array('id' => $Id));
    $arrayResults = $this->select($select)->toArray()
    return $arrayResults;
}
```

Comment: i'm looking to get an array of objects, not an array of arrays, for consistency sake

Comment: The `HydratingResultSet` implements the `Iterator` interface so you can already use `foreach` to loop over the results as if it were an array. If you really do need an array of objects you will have to manually construct the array using such a `foreach`.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by Steve, you can iterate the result set like an array. But if you need it as an actual array, ZF2 provides as iteratorToArray function that will convert it to an array for you.

```
public function fetchById($Id) {
    $select = $this->getSelect()->where(array('id' => $Id));
    $results = $this->select($select);

    return \Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($results);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590174/convert-zend-db-resultset-hydratingresultset-to-array-of-objects/16692849 If you post your answer there, I will accept it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like the second paramater $recursive should be false.